# Opt in the Matlab wrapper for LibRs when configuring CMake

Tags: matlab, cmake, sdk, intel, realsense

I have [this](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/matlab) instruction where I want to use a SDK to control a stereo camera with a wrapper in MATLAB.

Now I have the instruction:

> Opt in the Matlab wrapper for LibRs with `cmake .. -D... -DBUILD_MATLAB_BINDINGS:BOOL=ON` when configuring CMake

and I don't know where even to start. So my questions are:

- What is LibRs?
- How do I configure CMake and for what do I need it?
- And where do I write the command `cmake .. -D... -DBUILD_MATLAB_BINDINGS:BOOL=ON`?

Comment: Those same instructions say "libRealSense 2.x.x, or **LibRS** for short". If you want to build from source, you need to use CMake. The instructions say that when you use CMake, you'll have to set the option `BUILD_MATLAB_BINDINGS:BOOL` to the value `ON`. If you don't know how to use CMake, start by reading the CMake documentation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You said IF you want to build from source. So you are suggesting I don't have to do it?